# XSL - append value to existing attribute in XML node (HTML)

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to append value to some attribute in given node that matches a xsl-template

Here is my code. Can someone tell me why is's not working? :)

```
    <xsl:template match="//*[contains(@class,'right-aligned') and @style]">
       <xsl:variable name="currentAttributeValue" select="@style"/>
       <xsl:attribute name="style">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($currentAttributeValue, 'text-align: right !important;')"  />
       </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

I've also tried with calling a "helper" template with parameters:

```
    <xsl:template match="//*[contains(@class,'full-width') and @style]">
       <xsl:variable name="currentAttributeValue" select="@style"/>
       <xsl:call-template name="concat">
          <xsl:with-param name="first" select="$currentAttributeValue"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="second">width: 100% !important; display: inline-block;</xsl:with-param>
       </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```

and here is the helper:

```
    <xsl:template name="concat">
       <xsl:param name="first" />
       <xsl:param name="second" />
       <xsl:attribute name="style">
          <xsl:value-of select="$first" />
           <xsl:value-of select="$second" />
       </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

But this is not working either ... Any suggestions?

Comment: p.s. this is the XML input that i want to change:
<div style="width: 100% !important; display: inline-block;" class="secondary full-width right-aligned">Some Text</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to write a template for the attribute e.g. http://xsltransform.net/jxDigUy which does

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,'full-width')]/@style">
        <xsl:attribute name="style" select="concat(., 'text-align: right !important;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

With XSLT 1.0 you don't have the `select` attribute for `xsl:attribute` and therefore need to implement that template as

```
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,'full-width')]/@style">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(., 'text-align: right !important;')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for the reply. I wanted to ask ... Can the problem be that I'm trying to apply more templates in one node? In this case the div tag has 3 classes and for each class i have some xsl-template ... can that be a problem?

Comment: Unless you use different modes for the different templates or you use XSLT 2.0 and `xsl:next-match` or you have templates imported and you use apply-imports you will not be able to apply more than one template to the same node. So yes, if you have several templates with a `match` attribute and you want to apply them to the same nodes you have to ensure they are all used.

Comment: Here is the total of what I'm trying to do. I have HTML document with <style> which contains a CSS. I want all that CSS to make it inline in the elements of the body. The thing is for one element there can be multiple CSS styles and I want to apply them all. So i parsed them, make xpaths to locate all the elements and values that needs to be added. For each CSS row there is a XSL template. 

I'm not using 2.0 XSLT so, how can i do this with different modes. I can assign mode to each template, but how will it match with the node in the XML?

Comment: I am afraid it is difficult to solve a problem that you describe in a comment. You might consider asking a new question with minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code you have, output you get and output you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842324/how-to-apply-more-then-one-xsl-templates-on-one-xml-node

Answer (score 1):

From here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/xslt-appending-to-a-attribute/1669

The recommendation is:

```
<xsl:attribute name="attr">

    <!-- copy the current value of attr -->
    <xsl:value-of select="@attr" />

    <!-- add more to attr here -->
    blahblah

</xsl:attribute>
```

For more on the @: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

> @     Selects attributes